# Почему Chrome отдаёт локальный кэш при back и forward навигации (кнопками) игнорируя заголовки Cache-Control со значениями: must-revalidate, no-cache?

Tags: http, webbrowser, кэширование, backbutton

Возможно я что-то делаю не так или чего-то не понимаю... но ситуация следующая: web-приложение (ASP.NET) функционирующее на сервере (IIS 10) для определенных страниц создает зависимости (CacheDependency), при изменении которых связный с зависимостью ресурс (страница) перестает быть актуальной, возвращает клиенту свежую версию с заголовками:

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 18:03:49 GMT
```

... и это хорошо и правильно работает во всех браузерах, но лишь до тех пор пока клиент не ткнет кнопки навигации Back/Forward, в этом случае браузер отдает ресурс `from disk cache`. Для наглядности продемонстрирую заголовки для трех ситуаций.

1. Первое обращение к серверу за ресурсом:

   REQUEST

   ```
   GET [url] HTTP/1.1
   Host: [host]
   Connection: keep-alive
   Pragma: no-cache
   Cache-Control: no-cache
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
   DNT: 1
   Referer: [refer]
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   ```

   RESPONSE

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 18:03:49 GMT
   X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
   X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   Date: Mon, 07 Aug 2017 10:52:00 GMT
   Content-Length: 3323
   ```
2. Повторный запрос ресурса (при условии, что запрошенный ресурс на сервере не изменился)

   REQUEST

   ```
   GET [url] HTTP/1.1
   Host: [host]
   Connection: keep-alive
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
   Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
   DNT: 1
   Referer: [referer]
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
   Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
   If-Modified-Since: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 18:03:49 GMT
   ```

   RESPONSE

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
   Cache-Control: private, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Last-Modified: Sun, 06 Aug 2017 18:03:49 GMT
   Date: Mon, 07 Aug 2017 10:53:00 GMT
   ```
3. Запрос ресурса после навигации через кнопку Back: ресурс на сервере изменился или не изменился, уже не важно, так как браузер не отсылает запрос, а использует собственный кэш, выдавая такой ответ

   ```
   Request URL:[url]
   Request Method:GET
   Status Code:200 OK (from disk cache)
   ```

   на этот якобы-запрос

   ```
   ! Provisional headers are shown
   Referer:[referer]
   Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
   User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
   ```

Не могу понять в чем дело, помогите разобраться, необходимо добиться чтобы вне зависимости от того через какое действие (через кнопки или по ссылке, прямой ввод адреса в адресную строку и т.д.) браузер сверялся бы с заголовками отдаваемыми сервером и только после принимал решение: выдавать ресурс из собственного кэша (если узнал, что на сервере он остался актуальным) или загрузил бы свежую версию, узнав о том, что на сервере она появилась, т.е. собственная (браузерная) копия перестала быть актуальной. Спасибо.

Answer (score -1):

Ответили [на тостере](https://toster.ru/q/449373):

> К `cache-control` добавьте `no-store`

Comment: К сожалению, ссылка не является непосредственным ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Я рассматриваю это как спам

Comment: @D-side, ну что мешало просто перенести ответ?

Comment: @YvetteColomb, зря, наверное.

Comment: @Qwertiy автору ответа? Не знаю. Форумные привычки?

Comment: @PavelKarinin, в таких случаях надо писать ответ.

Comment: @D-side, автор-то тут впервые. Мог бы и ты сделать. Ну или хотя бы написать в комментарии, что так надо было сделать.

Comment: @Qwertiy я написал.

Comment: @D-side, надо было более понятно написать...

Comment: @Qwertiy я написал понятно. Если считаете, что я написал непонятно, вместо препираний со мной могли бы написать понятнее по меньшей мере раза три.

Comment: Хорошо, так что нет ответа - ссылка только ответ

Comment: @YvetteColomb we don't mind English in comments (too much), sometimes machine translators bork too much.

Comment: @D-side, [а это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702951/178988#comment1057735_708755) что?

Comment: @Qwertiy не знаю. Я не понял. Человек якобы ответ и написал :)

Comment: Я размещен на русском языке

Comment: @D-side, да... Слово пропустил. Хотел написать "сам ответ".

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/191475)

Comment: @kizoso уже добавлено, как можно наблюдать в цитате

Comment: Прошу прощения, что ответил ссылкой... исправлюсь